# Converting a dataframe to pandas datetime format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with below columns:

df1:

```
       DOU  Hr_y Min_y  Sec_y  Hr_x  Min_x  Sec_x
2017-09-02    12     5     16    16      5     16
2017-09-02    14    21     45    21      6     30
```

I wanted to convert the Hr_y,Min_y,Sec_y,Hr_x,Min_x,Sec_x to pandas datetime format.

what could be the syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create [`timedeltas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) by `hour`, `minute`s and `second`s and add to `datetime`s:

```
df['DOU'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOU'])

a = pd.to_timedelta(df.filter(regex='y$').astype(str).apply(':'.join, 1))
b = pd.to_timedelta(df.filter(regex='x$').astype(str).apply(':'.join, 1))

df['x'] = df['DOU'] + a
df['y'] = df['DOU'] + b
print (df)
         DOU  Hr_y  Min_y  Sec_y  Hr_x  Min_x  Sec_x                   x  \
0 2017-09-02    12      5     16    16      5     16 2017-09-02 12:05:16   
1 2017-09-02    14     21     45    21      6     30 2017-09-02 14:21:45   

                    y  
0 2017-09-02 16:05:16  
1 2017-09-02 21:06:30
```

Another solution is join all columns togther and then convert to datetimes:

```
df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOU'].astype(str) + 
                        df['Hr_x'].astype(str) + 
                        df['Min_x'].astype(str) + 
                       df['Sec_x'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d%H%M%S')

df['y'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOU'].astype(str) + 
                        df['Hr_y'].astype(str) + 
                        df['Min_y'].astype(str) + 
                       df['Sec_y'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d%H%M%S')
print (df)
          DOU  Hr_y  Min_y  Sec_y  Hr_x  Min_x  Sec_x                   x  \
0  2017-09-02    12      5     16    16      5     16 2017-09-02 16:51:06   
1  2017-09-02    14     21     45    21      6     30 2017-09-02 21:06:30   

                    y  
0 2017-09-02 12:51:06  
1 2017-09-02 14:21:45
```